# Adicionar parâmetros get com valore de um select/option na url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Tenho na pagina que lista os imóveis do meu site um formulário de busca e um select que faz a ordenação do resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema: Fazendo uma busca no formulario e passando na url os valores via get ctr=0&min=20000&max=999999&suites=3 etc. e logo após escolher uma opção de ordenação a url perdi esses valores porque a página é atualizada e faz uma ordenação do resultado geral. Quando seleciona uma opção de ordenação, eu quero ordenar o resultado que aparecer na página e por isso preciso que o parâmetro do filtro anterior se mantenha na url e que seja adicionado mais o parâmetro de ordenação.

Estou enviando a ação para ordenar dessa maneira e por isso perco os valores que estão na url:

```
$("select.ordenacao").change(function() {
        $("select.ordenacao").each(function() {
          str = $( this ).val();
          //alert(str);
            //$("#ordenar").submit();
            location.href = '?ordenacao=' + str;
        });
    });
```

alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Porque você não faz isso em ajax, ou restful? Assim não precisaria dar refresh na página.

Comment: Se você me mostrar um exemplo de como fazer isso com Ajax eu fico grato, ainda não conseguir entender muito bem como fazer requisições com Ajax em arquivos php e mostrar o resultado em um retorno.

Comment: O ajax trabalha de forma assíncrona, através de uma função anônima utilizando callback, você tem um retorno executado, dentro de um elemento que receberá essa ação, sem ter que dar um refresh novamente, ele faz isso de forma mascarada, em um script php.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro fazer isso em ajax:

```
$("select.ordenacao").change(function() {
        $("select.ordenacao").each(function() {
          str = $( this ).val();
              ordenar(str);
            //$("#ordenar").submit();
        });
});
var ordenar = function(str) {
       var saida = null;
             $.get('?ordenacao=' + str, function(e){
              saida = jQuery.parseJSON(e);       
             });
       return saida;
 };
```

Outra opção é capturar os valores da URL e dar o seu refresh novamente:

```
   $("select.ordenacao").change(function() {
            $("select.ordenacao").each(function() {
              str = $( this ).val();
              //alert(str);
                //$("#ordenar").submit();
                 location.href='?ctr='+getValueQS("ctr")+'&min='+getValueQS("min")+'&max='+getValueQS("max")+'&suites='+getValueQS("suites")+'&ordenar='+str;
            });
        });


    function getValueQS(key) {  
      return unescape(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + escape(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));  
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou com a segunda opção, porém os valores do parâmetro esta senda passado vazio: lista?ctgr=&city=&s=&d=&v=&vmin=&vmax=&id=&submit=&ordenacao=recentes. Dúvida: como posso definir um valor padrão para cada parâmetro?

Comment: Tentei assim mas não tive sucesso: location.href='lista?ctgr='+getValueQS(0)+'&city='+getValueQS(0)+'&s='+getValueQS(0)+'&d='+getValueQS(0)+'&v='+getValueQS(0)+'&vmin='+getValueQS(0)+'&vmax='+getValueQS(99999999999999)+'&submit='+getValueQS("submit")+'&ordenacao='+str;

Comment: Eu não entendi, como assim, funcionou, e não funcionou?

Comment: O método funciona... se vc executar ele no console dando a saída no `console.log()` ele está retornando a string na query. Não entendi esse zero.

Comment: Vc deveria pensar em fazer isso com ajax, vc iria sofrer menos.

Comment: Funcionou, somente alguns parâmetros os valores estão vazios:

Comment: lista?ctgr=&city=&s=&d=&v=&vmin=&vmax=&id=&submit=&ordenacao=recentes---------------- Dos parâmetros acima esses são passados vazios:   &s=&d=&v=&vmin=&vmax=-------------Já verifiquei o value do option e esta ok, por padrão é zero, caso o usuário não escolha uma opção.

Comment: em último caso é só fazer isso:
lista?ctgr=<?php echo $_GET['ctgr']; ?>&city=<?php echo $_GET['city'];?>...